# Unity C# interfaces causing "script class cannot be found"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2019.3.13f1 and Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.5.4. I have the script InterfaceContainer.cs as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InterfaceContainer : MonoBehaviour {

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        
    }

}

public interface IItem {

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Path { get; }
    public GameObject Icon { get; }

    public void Open();

}
```

Visual Studio gives no compilation errors.

In Unity the inspector of the script says "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name." And when I drag the script into a GameObject, it says "Can't add script component "InterfaceContainer" because this script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and the class name match."

The names definitely match, because when I deleted the interface part the error didn't exist anymore.
I also tried deleting the class part. It didn't help.
Any subsequent scripts added had the exact same error, whether or not they contain any interfaces, or reference this script.

The weird thing is when I deleted the interface part of this script, refreshed Unity, added this part again, and refreshed Unity again, the error disappears. However all subsequently added scripts still have the same error.

I have no idea what causes this error, and have googled for a long time with no avail. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The error isn't gone when I removed the interface part and added it again; I can still drag the script as a component, when when I try entering playmode it asks me to fix all compiler errors.

Comment: Do you have any other errors in the console? Unity does not recompile everything until **all** compiler errors are fixed!

Comment: Hey, not 100% sure, but I think you should not declare more than 1 Monobehaviour class per file, otherwise Unity doesn't like it. Try moving `IItem` to a separate file and see if it helps

Comment: @Ron `IItem` is no `class` and not a `MonoBehaviour`, though ;) Having an interface in a `MonoBehaviour` file is not beautiful but no issue

Comment: @derHugo I agree, but I did encounter this issue with one of the older versions of Unity, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Ron how old? This was never an issue at least since Unity 4 ^^ You can even have multiple `MonoBehaviour` classes within one file ... Unity will just only "know" the one matching with the file name (makes sometimes e.g. sense for generic or abstract types)

Comment: I tried moving the interface part into a seperate script `IItem.cs`. The same error occurs for both `InterfaceContainer` and `IItem`, even though `InterfaceContainer.cs` no longer contains `IItem`.

Comment: @derHugo Well I found the error. Unity decided to finally show the error instead just telling me there is: the `public` modifiers of the interface properties and methods are invalid. Visual Studio says no compiler errors for all my scripts tho...

Comment: @derHugo been with Unity since 2012, so I think we started at v3
not sure when I encountered this issue though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click in the Project Panel of Unity
2. `Import New Asset...` and select `InterfaceContainer.cs`
3. Try add this script as component again.

Comment: I tried doing what you say. If `InterfaceContainer.cs` is not already in my scripts folder then it imports the script, and it doesn't work. 
Otherwise it creates a duplicate `InterfaceContainer1.cs`, and none of the two works.

Comment: Could you remove the `public` modifiers from the `interface IItem` 's members (`Name, Path, Icon and Open`)? This script cannot be compiled if I keep these modifiers, and after removing, this script works well.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I would try is to check if it happens in earlier versions of unity. With the [unity hub](https://unity3d.com/es/get-unity/download) its easy to have different versions of unity to check this kind of things. Its useful if you are working with one of the latests.

I can confirm that in 2018.4.12, I attach my monobehaviours with interfaces with no problem.

On the other hand you dont implement the Interface you define in your monobehaviour, although that should not be causing any problem, have you tried if implementing the interface in your monobehaviour if you got the error?

Hope that helps

Comment: What spoke against multiple comments? ;) This is no answer to the question

Comment: might not be the correct answer, but it is an answer with 2 proposals for the asker to check, that once checked might also narrow the possibilities that cause the error. I think that what I propose is useful, and when I ask for help, I appreciate proposals and people efforts to guide me tho the issue I might be having, even if its not the straight answer to the problem

Comment: Well, as for your suggestions: I'm using `2019.3.13` and it is no issue at all to have an `interface` declaration within a `MonoBehaviour` file script .. you can even have multiple classes of type `MonoBehaviour` in one file (e.g. abstracts etc) .. Unity will just only know the one with a matching name. The issue here is something else we don't know yet

Comment: I have two more classes of type `MonoBehaviour` that implement `IItem`. Whether they are added or not, the error occurs for all scripts.
I tried using `2019.3.15f1` and the same error occurs.